# Make Optaplanner ignore redundant result

Tags: optaplanner

I'm having an issue where in my use case I want to just receive the best answer and return with that single best answer. I want the result as quickly as possible and want the nonimprovement timer to trigger as soon as possible.
A lot of times optaplanner will trigger a new solution is found and when reviewing the score, it is a score that was already found. Is there a way to have optaplanner not signal that it found a new solution that is better when it is the same exact score?

Apologies if this is simple to do, I'm new to optaplanner and couldn't find what I was looking for after searching around.

Could not find a way for optaplanner to not trigger when the same best score found.

EDIT:
I just remembered that because of the random seed (which we want to keep), I spawned 8 threads to solve the same problem. So each thread is individually coming up with the same best answer and notifying the main thread. So this is definitely not an optaplanner problem. Your answer just made me think of that. Thank you so much for answering in impressive timing.

The only thing I can think of is to track to see if the same results come up myself in the main application and keep a nonimprovement timer in the main application to kill the solver threads myself... I'll mark the solution as resolved since I was slow in realizing this is an issue in my application.

Comment: As for multiple threads running the solver, do you start them yourself to see if any solver brings a better solution than others (multi-bet solving), or do you use the multi-threaded solving feature of OptaPlanner?
See https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#multithreadedSolving.

Comment: I spawn several solver threads myself. I take the unimproved time that we pass into java and manually track to see if all the threads do not improve in that time and I call terminateEarly on them. Everything works how it should now, I feel dumb for not thinking about how I threaded the solvers right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OptaPlanner should fire the new best solution event only if the score has improved. If you see the event firing without any scope improvements, there might be two possible explanations:

1. a new best solution has been produced after submitting a [`ProblemChange`](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#problemChange), which is expected as this new best solution reflects an external change
2. there is a score corruption and, as a result, the score is incorrect; try turning on the [FULL_ASSERT](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#environmentMode) mode to confirm that